# Hi There, I am new to use JBOSS Fuse, i have download the zip file and extracted it . But its not working at all

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

```
ERROR: Bundle io.fabric8.fabric-zookeeper [53] Error starting mvn:io.fabric8/fabric-zookeeper/1.0.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-zookeeper [53]: Unable to resolve 53.0: missing requirement [53.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=15.0.0)(!(version>=16.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-zookeeper [53]: Unable to resolve 53.0: missing requirement [53.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=15.0.0)(!(version>=16.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle jackson-mapper-asl [54] Error starting mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.12 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle jackson-mapper-asl [54]: Unable to resolve 54.0: missing requirement [54.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.datatype))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle jackson-mapper-asl [54]: Unable to resolve 54.0: missing requirement [54.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.datatype)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  8% [=====>                                                                  ]ERROR: Bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt [56] Error starting mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt/1.9.1_1 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt [56]: Unable to resolve 56.0: missing requirement [56.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.crypto))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt [56]: Unable to resolve 56.0: missing requirement [56.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.crypto)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 11% [=======>                                                                ]ERROR: Bundle org.fusesource.insight.insight-log [59] Error starting mvn:org.fusesource.insight/insight-log/1.0.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.fusesource.insight.insight-log [59]: Unable to resolve 59.0: missing requirement [59.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.fusesource.insight.insight-log [59]: Unable to resolve 59.0: missing requirement [59.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle io.fabric8.fabric-agent [60] Error starting mvn:io.fabric8/fabric-agent/1.0.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-agent [60]: Unable to resolve 60.0: missing requirement [60.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=io.fabric8.api)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 62.0: missing requirement [62.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-agent [60]: Unable to resolve 60.0: missing requirement [60.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=io.fabric8.api)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 62.0: missing requirement [62.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle scala-library [61] Error starting mvn:com.weiglewilczek.scala-lang-osgi/scala-library/2.9.1 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle scala-library [61]: Unable to resolve 61.0: missing requirement [61.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle scala-library [61]: Unable to resolve 61.0: missing requirement [61.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle io.fabric8.fabric-api [62] Error starting mvn:io.fabric8/fabric-api/1.0.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-api [62]: Unable to resolve 62.0: missing requirement [62.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-api [62]: Unable to resolve 62.0: missing requirement [62.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle io.fabric8.fabric-boot-commands [63] Error starting mvn:io.fabric8/fabric-boot-commands/1.0.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-boot-commands [63]: Unable to resolve 63.0: missing requirement [63.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=15.0.0)(!(version>=16.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-boot-commands [63]: Unable to resolve 63.0: missing requirement [63.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=15.0.0)(!(version>=16.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch [64] Error starting mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch/0.1.49_1 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch [64]: Unable to resolve 64.0: missing requirement [64.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.crypto))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch [64]: Unable to resolve 64.0: missing requirement [64.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.crypto)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle io.fabric8.fabric-core [65] Error starting mvn:io.fabric8/fabric-core/1.0.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-core [65]: Unable to resolve 65.0: missing requirement [65.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=15.0.0)(!(version>=16.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-core [65]: Unable to resolve 65.0: missing requirement [65.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=15.0.0)(!(version>=16.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle io.fabric8.fabric-commands [66] Error starting mvn:io.fabric8/fabric-commands/1.0.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-commands [66]: Unable to resolve 66.0: missing requirement [66.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=15.0.0)(!(version>=16.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-commands [66]: Unable to resolve 66.0: missing requirement [66.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=15.0.0)(!(version>=16.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle io.fabric8.fabric-configadmin [67] Error starting mvn:io.fabric8/fabric-configadmin/1.0.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-configadmin [67]: Unable to resolve 67.0: missing requirement [67.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=io.fabric8.api)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 62.0: missing requirement [62.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle io.fabric8.fabric-configadmin [67]: Unable to resolve 67.0: missing requirement [67.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=io.fabric8.api)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 62.0: missing requirement [62.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle org.jboss.fuse.esb-commands [68] Error starting mvn:org.jboss.fuse/esb-commands/6.1.0.redhat-379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.jboss.fuse.esb-commands [68]: Unable to resolve 68.0: missing requirement [68.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.security.auth))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.jboss.fuse.esb-commands [68]: Unable to resolve 68.0: missing requirement [68.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.security.auth)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: This may help [how-to-install-jboss-fuse-guide-step-by-step](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/475/how-to-install-jboss-fuse-guide-step-by-step)

Comment: 6.1.0.GA is very old version. But `missing requirement [62.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers)` suggests that you're using some strange JDK version to run it. Which java version do you use?

Comment: JDK 1.7 @Grzegorz Grzybek

Comment: @Campiotti I have a written admin=admin,admin  in user.properties file still I am getting the same error. I am using this on windows 10 and tried starting the JBoss fuse with command "bin\start.bat".

Comment: Are you sure you've installed JDK instead of JRE?

Answer (score 1):

using redhat fuse 6.x will be perfect with java 6 and java 7 and not be stable or not working with java 8.
while I recommend using redhat fuse 7.x with Java 8 as it is more stable and supported right now.
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/250544

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the version of jboss fuse you are working with. If the version is 6.1 then you have to use either java 6 or java 7. If you are using higher version, Then you will get this error.

You can search for compatible version with downloaded fuse. Please check

etc/jre.properties in the fuse installation folder.